# Is it ever a good idea to append functions to a JavaScript Object Literal's __proto__ property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object-literal, proto

I have an object literal:

```
var tasks = {};
```

That I basically add things to like so:

```
function addTask(task) {
  tasks[task.id] = task
}
```

I want to modify that so that I can call a `start` function on each task. So:

```
var tasks = {};
tasks.__proto__.start = function(key) {
  // do stuff with this[key]
}

function addTask(task) {
  tasks[task.id] = task
  tasks.start(task.id)
}
```

I've heard that it's best to avoid the **proto** object and that it slows down execution. However I'm not re-assigning it, I'm appending to it.

Is there an alternative that would be considered better?

Comment: You need a constructor/factory function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really any need to use a prototype for this. You're not creating many instances where you need a common functionality abstracted at a higher level, you can just add a method on the `tasks` object.

```
const tasks = {
  start(key) {
    const task = this[key]
    // do stuff with task
  }
}

// example call
tasks.start('123');
```

If you want to make sure there's no clash with an existing key, you can use a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol) instead.

```
const startSymbol = Symbol('start');
const tasks = {
  [startSymbol](key) {
    const task = this[key]
    // do stuff with task
  }
}

// example call
tasks[startSymbol]('123');
```

You could also just have a standalone function that does this, similarly to your `addTask` function:

```
function start(tasks, key) {
  const task = tasks[key]
  // do stuff with task
}

// example call
start(tasks, '123')
```

Having this standalone function is probably better because you won't have to worry about clashes between your task keys and method names.

You could also create a wrapper object that does this separation:

```
const taskManager = {

  tasks: {} // map of key to task

  // methods
  add(task) {
    this.tasks[task.id] = task;
    this.start(task.id);
  }
  start(key) {
    const task = this.tasks[key];
    // do stuff with task
  }
}

// example usage
taskManager.start('123')
```

The advantage of this approach is that your `tasks` are encapsulated within a container that manipulates on them, constricting the scope in which `tasks` should be used and making it more clear (suggesting to the programmer) which functions are meant to be used on the tasks.

If you plan on having multiple task managers, then using prototypes might make sense here:

```
class TaskManager {
  constructor() {
    this.tasks = {}  // map of key to task
  }

  // methods
  add(task) {
    this.tasks[task.id] = task;
    this.start(task.id);
  }
  start(key) {
    const task = this.tasks[key];
    // do stuff with task
  }
}

// example usage
new TaskManager().start('123')
```

Comment: Thanks. Seeing a task manager entity is helpful, and didn't see it before

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to declare the task manager as 'var' semantically speaking? because the task manager will change over time....

Comment: `const` doesn't apply to the value but to the reference. You cannot point a variable declared with `const` to something else, but you can change the value itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good idea from both a performance and browser compatibility perspective.

See these warnings from [mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of
>   how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow
>   operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on
>   performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are
>   not limited to simply the time spent in obj.**proto** = ... statement,
>   but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose
>   [[Prototype]] has been altered. If you care about performance you
>   should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a
>   new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

--

> Warning: While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most
>   browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized
>   in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature to ensure
>   compatibility for web browsers. For better support, it is recommended
>   that only Object.getPrototypeOf() be used instead.